# In Jenkins pipeline using curl how can store response cookies?

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a Jenkins Pipeline using a sh command with curl.

Using a regular command prompt it is possible to store the response cookies and after that sending those cookies in another request, for instance to store the cookies

```
curl -k -c my_cookies.txt -X POST https://myLogin
```

and then send a request with those cookies

```
curl -k -b my_cookies.txt -X GET https://myGetRequest
```

Is it possible with Jenkins Pipeline to have something similar ?

I have tried something like:

```
final String url = "https://myLogin"
final String response = sh(script: "curl -c my_cookie.txt -k -X POST $url ", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

But this generates an error like

```
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `my_cookie.txt` may not be what you expect. Try debugging with a `readFile` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this :

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('call 1st api') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    curl --cookie-jar $WORKSPACE/cookie.txt https://62e96ddc0c77.ngrok.io/put
                """
            }
        }
        stage('call 2nd api') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    curl --cookie $WORKSPACE/cookie.txt https://62e96ddc0c77.ngrok.io/get 
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example if the first call is a success the cookie will store on `$WORKSPACE/cookie.txt` location and the 2nd call will read it from the same location.
`$WORKSPACE` - is the location of the Job workspace. you no need to hardcode the location, as Jenkins takes care it